# Have block level element fill 100% width of overflow-x: scroll container

Tags: html, css

I've got a container element that's a certain width, with `overflow-x: auto`. In it I have a block level header element (h1) that's supposed to, being a block element, fill the container horizontally. And it does so, as long as there are no other elements in the container that overflow, creating a horizontal scrollbar. If there are overflowing elements, then the header element fills only the non-overflowing horizontal space of the container, but doesn't appear in the overflowing space.

Fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rand0mbits/qUh3s/

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <table><tr><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td>
    <td>text</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
}

#one h1 {
    font-size 1.1em;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

table td {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

How do i make the `<h1>` fill the whole width of the container?

Comment: A cheap way for this specific example would be to set `width:200%` in `#one h1`, but I suppose you're looking for a more adaptive solution.

Comment: I don't think you can without the use of js but if it is a table you could add a table header that spanned the columns and add the h1 to that - http://jsfiddle.net/qUh3s/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `H1` is going to inherit the width of its parent element since it's relative, so it will always end up being the same width you set `#one` to.

What you can do is instead of `#one` having `overflow: auto`, wrap the table inside another `DIV` with `overflow: auto`. This way, `#one` stays a fixed width, but the wrapper around the table, allows the content to scroll horizontally.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yetti/Ggua5/

Answer (score 8):

See the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUh3s/2/)**.

Use the HTML `caption` element:

```
<div id="one">    

    <table>
        <caption>
            <h1>header</h1>
        </caption>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px;    
}

#one h1 {
    font-size 1.1em;
    background-color: blue;        
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

table td {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What you've done is moved the h1 inside the table. It'd be good to say this in the answer, because it may not be the solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is a more semantically correct answer, but as TylerH mentioned, the OP might not want the header in the table. +1 anyway

Comment: @user3657431 It's a working answer, yes, but it changes the markup of OPs code and the answer only says part of the change, which can be misleading and cause errors down the road if OP isn't aware that the h1 was moved inside the table. Good answers always describe everything they do. That's what.

Comment: @TylerH If the `h1` should be the caption of the `table` anyway (what I guessed) you get some extra semantic value to the markup.

Comment: Unfortunately, there may be other content in the container div besides the table. The `h1` is the header for the container, not the table.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**css**

```
#one {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
}

#one h1 {
    font-size 1.1em;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    position:relative;
}

table td {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
}

h1:after {
     content:"";
     background: blue;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
    left:100%
 }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUh3s/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Change this CSS code like the following then check and let me know if you want this:

```
#one {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
border: solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question... I think it's pretty specific that he wants to have a non-100% width div with overflow, and a full width element *inside* that overflowing div.

Comment: In that case I think he should use perfect pixels that will be the div size, right?

Comment: This doesn't work. If the content inside `#one` is wider than 100% (of the page or whatever element `#one` is in), then the header still only goes to 100%, not the full width.